# How to improve AVAssetExportSession saving performance

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avmutablevideocomposition

I'm using `AVAssetExportSession` to save video with some text / image overlays on it.
It's working pretty fine except It takes way to much time to save new video, I've seen other apps that do it much faster like 2-4x faster. So I'm wondering is there something I do in a wrong way?

Here is my code (I removed some unrelated parts for better reading bug if you would like to see realisation of some func please tell me):

```
 func saveVideo() {
    guard let fileURL = videoMediaURL else { return }

    let vidAsset = AVURLAsset(url: fileURL, options: nil)

    // Create an AVMutableComposition for editing
    let mutableComposition = getVideoComposition(asset: vidAsset)

    let videoTrack: AVAssetTrack = mutableComposition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
    var size = videoTrack.naturalSize

    //fixing native ios rotated video
    if videoTrack.preferredTransform.c == -1 {
        size = CGSize(width: size.height, height: size.width)
    }

    let isLandscape = size.width > size.height
    if videoTrack.preferredTransform.a == 1 && videoTrack.preferredTransform.d == 1 && isLandscape {
        size = CGSize(width: size.height, height: size.width)
    }

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: mutableComposition.duration)
    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)

    var transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform

    if transform.a == 1 && transform.d == 1 && isLandscape {
        let diff = size.height / size.width
        let scale = videoTrack.preferredTransform.xScale * diff
        transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform.translatedBy(x: (-size.width * scale) / 1.65, y: videoTrack.preferredTransform.yOffset).scaledBy(x: videoTrack.preferredTransform.xScale * diff, y: videoTrack.preferredTransform.yScale * diff)
    }

    if transform.tx >= 3840 {
        transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: transform.xOffset / 2)
    }

    layerInstruction.setTransform(transform, at: .zero)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]


    let containerLayer = setupLayers()

    let layerComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    layerComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(videoTrack.nominalFrameRate))
    layerComposition.renderSize = size
    layerComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: containerLayer)
    layerComposition.instructions = [instruction]

    //Remove existing file
    deleteFile(outputURL)

    //export the video to as per your requirement conversion
    if let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) {
        self.exportSession = exportSession
        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4v
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exportSession.videoComposition = layerComposition
        // try to export the file and handle the status cases
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            //handle exportSession result

        })
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is it because of `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality`?

Comment: @matt I have to deliver good quality video, so can't set lower quality.
Still I can see other apps that export high quality video much faster

Comment: How long does it take to export? Do you have sample input and output files?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman it's around 10 seconds for 10 sec 4k video, I can upload sample input/output video

Comment: @RhythmicFistman https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g9lfxqtolh8m6xq/AAC7T2jQbTVr4lh03W5bxOz1a?dl=0

Comment: the frame rates are the same. you're re-encoding a 4k file, how long is it taking for you?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman it takes about 10 sec.

Answer (score 0):

I am chasing this issue with `AVAssetExportSession` which may be linked to this [AVAssetExportSession never starts on older devices, device needs to be rebooted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576443/avassetexportsession-never-starts-on-older-devices-device-needs-to-be-rebooted).

Have you been able to resolve your issue? I am asking since the two issue are close in time and may be caused by a bug in iOS 14.3.

Comment: have you found something? I have the same problem on iOS 14.3, 14.4